# Hive query generation is taking long time to generate dataset

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I am trying to run hive query on huge amount of data(almost in half of petabyte), and these query running map reduce internally. it takes very long time to generate the data set(map reduce to complete) what optimization mechanism for hive and Hadoop i can use to make these query faster, one more important question i have does the amount of disk available for map reduce or in /tmp directory is important for faster map reduce?

Comment: What had been tried to make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

There is not too much you can do, but I can give a few direction what usually can be done with Hive: 
You should select SQLs which cause less shuffling. For example you can try to cause map side joins when possible. You can also do some operations in a way that will lead to map-only queries.

Another way is to tune number of reducers - sometimes Hive defines much less reducers then needed - so you can set it manually to better utilize your cluster 
If you have number of queries to run to do your transformation - you can define low replication factor for this temporary data in HDFS 
More help can be provided if we have info what are you doing.